# how to create custom contact form based on base contact form in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, forms, form-validation

I am creating a order form i used default magento contact form add many extra fields also defined in admin but how can i link form with template in admin ?

because i want contact us form should stay same and order form should work separately.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Tbh I don't know what you mean with "link form with template in admin", but this should help you to get started with a custom contact form: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066127/custom-forms-in-magento/32610321#32610321

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with link up to admin template? As an alternative approach using layout handles to inject layouts tgat allows targetting via layout directives. Check the idea under Dynamic handles section on how to create custom contact us fors with injected additional form elements. https://github.com/ProxiBlue/GlobalHandle/blob/master/README.md